# Remove icon from pyinstaller when creating command line tool

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I'm using windows and I've just created this command line tool. I'm trying to package it with pyinstaller and since its a command line tool, I don't want any icon on it including pyinstaller's default icon. I tried setting icon=none at the spec file side but still it created it with the icon. Any Idea how to solve it?

Comment: What exactly do you expect to see in windows, when you say "no icon"? Even files without an extension have an icon. Anyway, you won't see any icons when you are using the command line.

Comment: I want it to be like py2exe as in when you make an executable and don't specify any icon.

Comment: Also looking for the solution. "no icon" means that it takes windows default icon. I simply want to remove the default "diskette" icon

Answer (score 4):

I know that this is really old post, but you can always remove icon by using the argument `-i "NONE"`, for example

```
pyinstaller file.py -i "NONE"
```